# Appended content do not get the proper CSS style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

New appended content do not get the same design as the existing ones.

**Here my full code:**

HTML

```
<!-- Top Bar -->
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


                <!-- Notifications -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                        <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
                        <span class="label-count">7</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="header">NOTIFICATIONS</li>
                        <li class="body">
                            <ul class="menu" id="append">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-light-green">
                                            <i class="material-icons">person_add</i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="menu-info">
                                            <h4>12 new members joined</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> 14 mins ago
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-cyan">
                                            <i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="menu-info">
                                            <h4>4 sales made</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> 22 mins ago
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-red">
                                            <i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="menu-info">
                                            <h4><b>Nancy Doe</b> deleted account</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> 3 hours ago
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-orange">
                                            <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="menu-info">
                                            <h4><b>Nancy</b> changed name</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> 2 hours ago
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-blue-grey">
                                            <i class="material-icons">comment</i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="menu-info">
                                            <h4><b>John</b> commented your post</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> 4 hours ago
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-light-green">
                                            <i class="material-icons">cached</i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="menu-info">
                                            <h4><b>John</b> updated status</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> 3 hours ago
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-purple">
                                            <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="menu-info">
                                            <h4>Settings updated</h4>
                                            <p>
                                                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> Yesterday
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="footer">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">View All Notifications</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- #END# Notifications -->



            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<br/><br/> <br/><br/> <br/><br/>
<a href="#" class="append">Append it</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$( document.body ).on( 'click', '.append', function( event ) {

      $("#append").append(
                                    "<li>"+
                                        "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">"+
                                            "<div class=\"icon-circle bg-purple\">"+
                                                "<i class=\"material-icons\">settings</i>"+
                                            "</div>"+
                                            "<div class=\"menu-info\">"+
                                                "<h4>Just make a small Test to see the problem</h4>"+
                                                "<p>"+
                                                    "<i class=\"material-icons\">access_time</i> Yesterday"+
                                                "</p>"+
                                            "</div>"+
                                        "</a>"+
                                    "</li>"
      );

      return false;

});
```

**A real example to test it and see my problem:**

https://jsfiddle.net/Lr7gn020/1/

**To reproduce my problem:**

- Click on Append it link
- Then click on Notification dropdown menu and scroll down into the last `<li>` row, and you will see that the design of appended rows is not like the others.

Please help to figure it out.

Comment: You can use single quote (') instead of inner  double code

Comment: @MichaelCoker You didn't made a fix on my existing code, i want a solution for a long text problem. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Why i posted the code like that ? to be changed by small text ? already solved the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a couple of classes when you append the new items. The `a` tag in the original items has the `waves-effect` and `waves-block` classes applied, but you're not giving it those in the newly added elements.

Try changing `"<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">"` to `"<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\" waves-effect waves-block\">"`

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lr7gn020/3/

Comment: When I look at your updated Fiddle I still see that the last list-item drops down underneath the icon.

Comment: Yep. This is because the text is too long for the container. That's a separate issue, and one that can be easily fixed in the CSS for all the items.

Comment: ah gotcha, I must have been misunderstanding the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have forked your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9f9107tk/) with a minor adjustment. The only thing that is preventing the styling from being the same as the others is the amount of content that is in the `h4` under the `menu-info` div. When I deleted some of the text, leaving only "Just make a small Test" it appears like all the other list items. The text was making it so the width of the div was larger than the area given to the right of the icon which is why it was dropping down.

Your anchor tag is also missing the two classes `waves-effect waves-block`. If you are adding these 2 classes with JS you will need to reinitialize the function that does this after the item is appended.

UPDATE

If you need to have that much content then just simply add a `max-width: 200px` to your `.menu-info` class. [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9f9107tk/2/)

Comment: Yes, and it is exactly the problem i want resolve ! I want use a long text on my dropdown menu.